# How can I display a list of child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent-child, partial-views

I have a table of accounts and venues where an account can have many venues.

I'm displaying all the accounts as partials on the accounts index page and would like for each one to include the names of the venues linked to them.

Heres what I have:

**account partial**

```
<%= link_to free_account do %>      
    <div class="account_partial">          
      <span class="account_header"><%= free_account.name %></span> - <span class="free_account_highlight">(<%= free_account.role %>)</span><br>

      <%= render :partial => 'venues/account_venue', :collection => @account.venues %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**account_venue partial**

```
<%= venue.name %>
```

I'm getting this error:

> NoMethodError in Accounts#index
>
> undefined method `venues' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #12):
>
> 12:       <%= render :partial => 'venues/account_venue',
>   :collection => @account.venues %>

Any help would be much appreciated!

**edit**

**accounts_controller**

```
    class AccountsController < ApplicationController   
    load_and_authorize_resource  

      def index
        @accounts = Account.all(:include => :venues)
      end      
    end
```

**accounts index.html.erb**

```
<div id="narrow_container">
  <div class="free_accounts_container">
    <h2 class="show_orange">Free accounts</h3>  
    <%= render :partial => 'free_account', :collection => @accounts %>
  </div>

  <div class="premium_accounts_container">
    <h2 class="show_orange">Premium accounts</h3>
    <%= render :partial => 'premium_account', :collection => @accounts %><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="clearall"></div>

  <div class="button">
    <%= link_to 'add account', new_account_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_free_account.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to free_account do %>
  <% if free_account.role == "free" %>
    <div class="account_partial">

      <span class="account_header"><%= free_account.name %></span> - <span class="free_account_highlight">(<%= free_account.role %>)</span><br>

      <div class="owner_details">
        <span class="pre_account_highlight">Owners username:</span><span class="account_highlight"><%= free_account.user.username %></span>
        <span class="pre_account_highlight">Owners e-mail:</span><span class="account_highlight"><%= free_account.user.email %></span>
      </div>

      <div class="account_details">     
      </div>

      <%= render :partial => 'venues/account_venue', :collection => @account.venues %>
    </div>
  <% else %>         
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**update**

If I change the partial call to:

```
<%= render :partial => 'venues/account_venue', :collection => @accounts %>
```

and the account_venue partial to just read 'test' it loads without error but displays the word test 4 times (theres 4 account records) if I add a new account record it displays the word test 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set @account to something in your controller, and that model instance should be joined to (or include) the Venues model. Like so:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id], :include => :venues)
```

**Edit:** I take it you have already set up your Account and Venue models with has_many and belongs_to relationships?

**Edit two:** I see now that you're trying to access Accounts#index, in which case the code above should be changed to something like (since we're not looking at one specific account):

```
@accounts = Account.all(:include => :venues)
```

**Edit three:** Now that you've posted the controller and partials code as well, a couple of things stand out; When rendering a partial using a collection the resulting object inside the partial derives its name from the partial and not the collection. From the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

> "When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial."

In your partial `_account_venue.html.erb` you have `<%= venue.name %>` - this needs to be  changed to `<%= account_venue.name %>`.

Secondly, in `_free_account.html.erb`, where you call the `account_venue` partial, you're referring to a collection object named `@account` - where does this come from? Since the `free_account` partial is *also* called with a collection, the object you should be using will be called `free_account` - indeed you are referencing it by this name earlier in the same partial when you do `<%= free_account.name %>`. So the render partial call should look like this:

`<%= render :partial => 'venues/account_venue', :collection => free_account.venues %>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have set up the relationships that bit of code gives a "Couldn't find Account without an ID" error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, please see "edit two" above - I didn't spot that you were calling the `index` method so I assumed `show`, which would have an ID param.

Comment: Also, if `@account` is really a collection you ought to rename it to `@accounts`

Comment: Thanks for the extra input, It's still giving the original error tho.

Comment: Oh and the contents of views/accounts/index.html.erb as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your not assigning `@account` to anything. Should this be `free_account` instead?